# How we can pass API payload in Step Function Dynamically?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I created a Step function which will trigger by API Gateway with Input Parameters. Graph is here :

[image: Step Function Graph]

Below is my Step function code :

[[image: Step Function Code2]

I'm trying to pass Body via API Gateway like below:

[image: API Gateway Body request]

I'm getting below error while body request to API gateway

{
"error": "States.Runtime",
"cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'API Gateway Invoke' (entered at the event id #2). The JSONPath '$.id' specified for the field 'Payload.$' could not be found in the input '{"ISIN":"12sd"}'"
}